# Cloudera QuickStarts VM on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I am currently using ubuntu 14.04(no windows) on my laptop. Is it mandatory for me to install Virtualbox or VMware to use Cloudera QuickStarts Vm on it.

Comment: So, you're asking if you have to install a virtual machine software to use a virtual machine? Yes... Of course. Or you can install Hadoop directly into your Ubuntu system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Cloudera](http://www.cloudera.com/downloads/quickstart_vms/5-8.html)

> These 64-bit VMs require a 64-bit host OS and a virtualization product that can support a 64-bit guest OS.

And

> Cloudera QuickStart VMs are available as Zip archives in VMware, KVM, and VirtualBox formats

So yes, you need a virtualization product.
Also because the file you will download is just an image and it requires a virtualizer that can play it and let you interact with it.

Comment: Also available as Docker containers

Comment: Yeah Docker would fit better on Linux